# Scilab plots in -nogui mode

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave, scilab

Is it possible to plot graphs when running Scialb in -nogui mode ?
I tried the following :

```
saket@launchpad:~$scilab -nogui
-->x=[1:10];
-->y= sin(x);
-->plot2d(x,y)
```

which gives the following error:

plot2d(x,y)

```
 !--error 999 
 Scilab graphic module disabled -nogui or -nwni mode.
```

Is there workaround for this . For example  I called an octave instance for plotting this way :

```
 octave --persist --eval 'x=[1:10];y=sin(x);plot(x,y);'
```

Is it possible to do it the Sciulab way itself without using octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Scilab -nw (or scilab-adv-cli)

Comment: I get the error message `Scilab 'figure' function disabled in -nogui or -nwni mode.` Any solution to this one?